# Perform action inside stream of operation in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a requirement to get the count of employees where employee name contains "kumar" and age is greater than 26. I am using Java 8 streams to iterate over the collection and I'm able to find employee count with above said condition.

But, in the meantime, I need to print the employee details.

Here's my code using Java 8 streams:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

    empList.add(new Employee("john kumar", 25));
    empList.add(new Employee("raja", 28));
    empList.add(new Employee("hari kumar", 30));

    long count = empList.stream().filter(e -> e.getName().contains("kumar"))
                          .filter(e -> e.getAge() > 26).count();
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Traditional way:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

    empList.add(new Employee("john kumar", 25));
    empList.add(new Employee("raja", 28));
    empList.add(new Employee("hari kumar", 30));
    int count = 0;
    for (Employee employee : empList) {

        if(employee.getName().contains("kumar")){
            if(employee.getAge() > 26)
            {
                System.out.println("emp details :: " + employee.toString());
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
     System.out.println(count);
}
```

Whatever I am printing in the traditional way, I want to achieve the same using streams also.

How do I print a message within each iteration when using streams?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the [`Stream.peek(action)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) method to log info about each object of your stream :

```
long count = empList.stream().filter(e -> e.getName().contains("kumar"))
                      .filter(e -> e.getAge() > 26)
                      .peek(System.out::println)
                      .count();
```

The `peek` method allows performing an action on each element from the stream as they are consumed. The action must conform to the [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface: take a single parameter `t` of type `T` (type of the stream element) and return `void`.

Comment: It should be emphasized that `peek` only performs an action on *processed* items so if you use a short-circuiting terminal action like `findFirst`, it will not necessarily process all items. Further, `count()` may skip the processing entirely if the size is predictable, e.g. without the `filter`s. The Java 9 implementation has such an optimization…

Comment: Is there a way to control peek(). In production I want to disable peek() method logs, One way is to commenting in code but it needs compilation of code and deployment . Any other idea?.

Comment: @Krishna The idea is not to disable `peek` but use a logging framework that will log differently in dev and production (based on a configuration file). Take a look at `log4j`.

Comment: @krishna  yes, if you do something like `.peek(() -> logger.debug("Message"))`   then the interface defined/used knows to call logger.isEnabled for you and you don't need to worry about it.  see p.42 of Java 8 Lambdas book.

Comment: if your action is not a consumer, you can add the curly brackets`.peek(() -> {doSomething();})`

Answer (score 2):

Rather unclear, what you actually want, but this might help:
Lambdas (like your `Predicate`) can be written in two ways:
Without brackets like this: `e -> e.getAge() > 26` or

```
...filter(e -> {
              //do whatever you want to do with e here 

              return e -> e.getAge() > 26;
          })...
```

Comment: Want print the output of  stream one before passing to next stream of operation.